# How to add a required custom field to the client database

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Firts of all, I have absolutely no knowledge about how magento works, I was going through how to make a theme, and apparently from what I understand, the theme has nothing to do with the process, like processing orders.

I need to ask **document number** of the customer in order to make the bill, so how add field to the **checkout process** and it must be a required value.

Please guide me the process flow of magento

Comment: It's a little unclear what you need to get - which document number? More specifics please.

Comment: well, in south american countries, when you sell something most of the time you need an ID number to purchase. I'm not sure if elsewhere is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial it may help you

- http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/

or

- https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/

Comment: thanks for the input, but just wondering, If I buy another theme, would I have to move all those files to the theme folder?

Comment: Yes, I suggest first to buy theme which you have chosen and customize your code so that you don't need to move all those file because it may possible new theme have modified some checkout files for changing layout/design purpose then if you move/replace files that will lost new theme layout for that particular page. Just try to simplify things :)